# Text gets pushed out of screen and not downward when using FlatList

Tags: react-native

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBl5S.png)I have 4 words in a text component and I'm trying to only get two of them to show on each line but when I marginRight the text to push the last two to the next line, they get rendered outside of the screen

```
    renderItem({item}){
    return( 
    <View>
        <Text style={{marginRight: 150}}>
            {item.company.toLowerCase()}
        </Text>
    </View>
    )
    }    

    render(){
    return(
        <FlatList
        style={{width: '100%'}}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.container} 
        data={this.props.WelcomeReducer}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={welcome => welcome.id}
        />
    )
    }
    }

     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingVertical: 25
    }
    })
```

Comment: Are you trying to make 4 words appear 2 words each?

Comment: Add a screenshot to explain the error more precisely

Comment: I added a screenshot, I'm trying to get the last 2 words to appear on the next line and not not get pushed out of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `numberOfLines` and `ellipsizeMode` props of the `Text` component.

[Text Comonent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#numberoflines)

Comment: Tried it, Same result

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding numColumns={2} props to my FlatList